# Abstract Method for a Base Class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I've got a base class called **DAL_Base** for a large project that does most of the SQL lifting.

**DAL_Base** has fields for `SELECT` statements, a `GetRecords()` method, and a `virtual FillData(IDataRecord)`.

```
public class DAL_Base<T> where T : IDisposable, new() {

  private string connStr;

  public DAL_Base() {
    connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompanyDatabaseConnStr"].ConnectionString;
  }

  internal string SP_GET { get; set; }

  internal SqlConnection m_openConn {
    get {
      var obj = new SqlConnection(connStr);
      obj.Open();
      return obj;
    }
  }

  internal virtual T FillDataRecord(IDataRecord record) {
    return new T();
  }

  internal TList<T> Get() {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SP_GET)) {
      throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Get Procedure does not exist for {0}.", typeof(T)));
    }
    var list = new TList<T>();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_GET, m_openConn)) {
      cmd.CommandType = cmd.GetCommandTextType();
      using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (r.Read()) {
          list.Add(FillDataRecord(r));
        }
      }
      cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    return list;
  }

}
```

There is a lot more, but this should suffice for a single example.

**TList** is just a `List<T>` class:

```
internal class TList<T> : List<T> {
  public TList() { }
}
```

When one of my classes inherits from it, I wanted it to be able to override the base class's `FillDataRecord(IDataRecord)`.

For example, **EmployeeDB ** inherits **DAL_BASE**.

When I call `EmployeeDB.GetEmployeeList()`, it uses **DAL_BASE** to pull the records:

```
public class EmployeeDB : DAL_Base<Employee> {

  private static EmployeeDB one;

  static EmployeeDB() {
    one = new EmployeeDB() {
      SP_GET = "getEmployeeList",
    };
  }

  private EmployeeDB() { }

  internal override Employee FillDataRecord(IDataRecord record) {
    var item = base.FillDataRecord(record);
    item.Emp_Login = record.Str("Emp_Login");
    item.Emp_Name = record.Str("Emp_Name");
    item.Emp_Email = record.Str("Emp_Email");
    item.Emp_Phone = record.Str("Emp_Phone");
    item.Emp_Role = record.Str("Emp_Role");
    return item;
  }

  public static EmployeeList GetEmployeeList() {
    var list = new EmployeeList();
    list.AddRange(one.Get());
    return list;
  }

}
```

In the code above, when `GetEmployeeList()` calls the **DAL_Base** method `Get()`, only **DAL_Base::FillDataRecord(IDataRecord)** is called.

I really need **EmployeeDB::FillDataRecord(IDataRecord)** to be called, but I can't make **DAL_Base::FillDataRecord(IDataRecord)** abstract.

What is the way around this?

All I know of right now is to create an `EventHandler`, which is what I just thought of, so I'm going to work towards that.

If anyone knows of a better route, please chime in!

Comment: Basically I wouldn't go with the eventhandler because you'll be forced to subscribe to an event in your child classes. Other options actually depends on how much freedom you have in the base class.

Comment: Does any code in `DAL_Base` call `DAL_Base::FillDataRecord(IDataRecord)`? Okay, I see that it does. No need to answer this question.

Comment: Can't you just require the FillDataRecord functionality to be passed to the Get method as delegate?

Comment: I have just tested your code by my side and it worked just as you expected : EmployeeDB::FillDataRecord(IDataRecord) is called. Defining FillDataRecord as virtual in the base class, and overriding it in the child class should be enough to achieve what you need.  You are saying that your DAL_Base is pretty big, maybe there is something in it that is responsible of that strange behavior? Is there some other methods called FillDataRecord in your base class? I guess EmployeeList is simply derived from TList<Employee>?

Comment: @galenus: +1 on that idea. I believe that is what Keith suggested in his answer that he posted about an hour before your comment.

Comment: @AirL: +1. Maybe it is because I am doing this in the debugger, but when I call of `EmployeeDB.GetEmployeeList()`, the call `one.Get()` is calling `DAL_Base.Get()`. When `DAL_Base` calls `Get()`, the line `list.Add(FillDataRecord(r))` only steps into `DAL_Base.FillDataRecord(IDataRecord)`.

Comment: @jp2code: almost the same one,  except moving the requirement closer to the point of consumption. BTW,  I believe that the delegate will have to point to a static method in the case of constructor injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to pass a delegate for Derived.FillDataRecord to the base class via the constructor.

```
public class DAL_Base<T> where T : IDisposable, new() {

  private string connStr;

  public DAL_Base() {
    connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompanyDatabaseConnStr"].ConnectionString;
  }
    private Func<IDataRecord, T> _fillFunc;

    public DAL_Base(Func<IDataRecord, T> fillFunc) : this() {
            _fillFunc = fillFunc;
    }

        // ... 
    internal TList<T> Get() {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SP_GET)) {
      throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Get Procedure does not exist for {0}.", typeof(T)));
    }
    var list = new TList<T>();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_GET, m_openConn)) {
      cmd.CommandType = cmd.GetCommandTextType();
      using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (r.Read()) {
          list.Add(_fullFunc(r));
}
```

and in the derived class:

```
public class EmployeeDB : DAL_Base<Employee> {
    public EmployeeDB() : base(r => FillDataRecord(r)) { }

  private Employee FillDataRecord(IDataRecord record) {
    var item = base.FillDataRecord(record);
    item.Emp_Login = record.Str("Emp_Login");
    item.Emp_Name = record.Str("Emp_Name");
    item.Emp_Email = record.Str("Emp_Email");
    item.Emp_Phone = record.Str("Emp_Phone");
    item.Emp_Role = record.Str("Emp_Role");
    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. I like this approach. The code is at work and I'm at home now, but I'll be checking on this idea tomorrow.

Comment: I wished I could write **Func<>** methods that easily. Every time, I have to think about them for a long time, then look up online how to implement them again.